# Is there a way to (easily) use text editor instead of graphical for traffic logic?

Tags: anylogic

I have relatively large traffic map, so if I try to edit the car spawning/routing/exiting/logical branching controls and move them around, the editor reacts slowly. I would probably prefer using text editor, so I can insert the values in bulk, (and then do something else while the editor is dealing with it) and also take bigger advantage of copying text.

However, I do not know where to find it. Any help? Or does AnyLogic allow only graphical editing?

Answer (score 0):

For graphical editing, there are 2 options here:

You can easily split your model into chunks. Either put them into different agent types or even across several models. Much lighter during development using the GUI. And the latter even allows working with several people in parallel.

The former is easier to setup, though.

If you want to get into developing models *without* any graphical editing, this is also possible. See [my AnyLogic workshop](https://youtu.be/casVdmKC-S0) on the topic as a starter. You need to have a solid foundation in OOP and Java though.

Comment: How would I solve the issue with referencing road objects? Mind you, I mostly work with the "spawn car" or "drive to" controls, for which I need to specify the object on roadNetwork. My map also consists of 1 average town, so I cannot do thing like splitting it into 2 parts.

As for the graphical/text editing, isn't the Java code generated "under" the hood? I thought it's similar to the Windows Forms, which allows you to set up the window in both ways. Therefore I could write a code which would create the graphical interface (so in a reverse way).

Comment: check my tutorial. Although it is for the Material-handling library, many concepts are similar in the road-traffic library. Try to do that yourself. Then open new, specific questions (not 3 questions together ;) ). ´(StackOverflow is not a discussion, back-and-forth place).